# How to reinstall the network manager with all its dependencies offline in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I installed the newer kernel version `linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic` because of a key error related to installed packages with unmet dependencies. After the installation there was no Ethernet nor wireless connection available anymore.

So I downgraded to the older kernel version `linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic`. This did not change anything. In fact, I still get an error message related to installed packages with missing dependencies.

I tried to reinstall the network manager packager offline (with the `sudo dpkg -i network-manager*.deb` command) but dependency problems prevent the configuration of the Network Manager. E.g. neither the dependencies `libndp0` nor the `libteamdctl0` are installed.

How do I install the Network Manager with all its missing dependencies offline?

In general, I would appreciate every suggestion you have concerning the problem with installed packages with missing dependencies.

Comment: The interesting takeaway here would probably be which errors you faced, and exactly what you did to help it (which presumably made things worse). It would have been nice to have the exact error messages you speak of: 1) *key error related to installed packages with unmet dependencies*, 2) *I still get an error message related to installed packages with missing dependencies*, 3) *dependency problems prevent the configuration of the network-manager*. Without these exact error messages, it's difficult to offer any solid advice on how to prevent such things happening again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: See the above for answers to your current issue (but this will not help you prevent similar accidents in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helpful advice. The solution for the problem with the Network Manager seem to be simpler than I thought. I just installed the missing packages listed below by the command line.

This was the output of the `sudo dpkg -i network-manager*.deb` command:

```
(Reading database ... 171577 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack network-manager_1.36.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager (1.36.4-2ubuntu1) over (1.36.4-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
network-manager depends on libndp0 (>= 1.2); however:
 Package libndp0 is not installed.
network-manager depends on libnm0 (= 1.36.4-2ubuntu1); however:
Version of libnm0:amd64 on system is 1.36.6-0ubuntu2.
network-manager depends on libteamdctl0 (>= 1.9); however:
Package libteamdctl0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
network-manager
```

However, if I try to boot the system with the newer kernel `linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic` I lose Ethernet and Wireless connection again, although the Network Manager was successfully installed.