# Connection activation failed of Ubuntu 22.04 Hotspot

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, android, hot-spot

After reinstalling the Network Manager with all its missing dependencies (see for details [How to reinstall the network manager with all its dependencies offline in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461412/how-to-reinstall-the-network-manager-with-all-its-dependencies-offline-in-ubuntu)) I tried to connect my phone (Android 10 version) to the Ubuntu Hotspot as I usually did without problems before reinstalling the Network Manager. I worked through all the suggestions in [Can't connect to ubuntu 22.04 hotspot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406149/cant-connect-to-ubuntu-22-04-hotspot). Unfortunately, none of this worked for me.
When I run the command `nmcli dev wifi hotspot` I get the following: `Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).`
Turning on Wi-Fi Hotspot is possible and the network is visible for my other device. However, as soon as I try to connect I get the error message "Connection failed Activation of network connection failed". Then, the message "Couldn't get IP-address" appears under the network name.